# Find duplicates from same table and constraint them from another table in sql

Tags: mysql

Oh, my title is not the best one and as English is not my main language maybe someone can fix that instead of downvoting if they've understood the issue here.

Basically i have two tables - tourneyplayers and results. Tourneyplayers is like a side table which gathers together tournament information across multiple tables - results, tournaments, players etc. I want to check duplicates from the results table over column day1_best, from single tournament and return all the tourneyplayers who have duplicates.

Tourneyplayers contain rows:

```
Tourneyplayers
tp_id | resultid | tourneyid
1     | 2        | 91
2     | 21       | 91
3     | 29       | 91
4     | 1        | 91
5     | 3        | 92
```

Results contains rows:

```
Results:
r_id | day1_best
1    | 3
2    | 1
3    | 4
..   | ..
21   | 1
..   | ..
29   | 2
```

Now tourney with id = 91 has in total 4 results, with id's 1,2,21 and 29. I want to return values which have duplicates, so currently the result would be

```
Result
tp_id | resultid | day1_best
1     | 2        | 1
2     | 21       | 1
```

I tried writing something like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tourneyplayers
WHERE resultid
IN (

SELECT r1.r_id
FROM results AS r1
INNER JOIN results AS r2 ON ( r1.day1_best = r2.day1_best ) 
AND (
r1.r_id <> r2.r_id
)
)
AND tourneyid =91
```

But in addition to values which had the same day1_best it chose two more which did not have the same. How could i improve my SQL or rewrite it?

Comment: Your example isnt complete. Why your result doesnt have resultid 1 or 29 ?

Comment: The result is what i'd like to get, resultid 1 has day1_best with a value of 3 and resultid 29 has day1_best with a value of 2, they're not duplicates.

Comment: I dont see the duplicates, sorry but for me doesnt have sense.

Comment: Umm, there are two rows (r_id=2 and r_id=21) which have day1_best with a value of 1, that's a duplicate in a column day1_best? Or have i misunderstood something?

Comment: looks like you dont need check `Tourneyplayers` only check for repeat on the `Result`

Comment: In that case i will get over all the results, i need to limit my search down to tourneyid.

Comment: What are the values that you get that you are not supposed to get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you `JOIN` both tables, so you know how the data looks like.

```
SELECT *
FROM tourney_players t
JOIN results r
  ON t.`resultid` = r.`r_id`;
```

Then using the same query you `GROUP` to see what `tourneyid, day1_best` combination has multiple rows

```
SELECT `tourneyid`, `day1_best`, count(*) as total
FROM tourney_players t
JOIN results r
  ON t.`resultid` = r.`r_id`
GROUP BY `tourneyid`, `day1_best`;
```

Finally you use the base `JOIN` and perform a `LEFT JOIN` to see what rows has a match and show only those rows.

```
SELECT t.`tp_id`, r.`r_id`, r.`day1_best`
FROM tourney_players t
JOIN results r
  ON t.`resultid` = r.`r_id`
LEFT JOIN (SELECT `tourneyid`, `day1_best`, count(*) as total
           FROM tourney_players t
           JOIN results r
             ON t.`resultid` = r.`r_id`
           GROUP BY `tourneyid`, `day1_best`
           HAVING count(*) > 1) as filter           
  ON t.`tourneyid` = filter.`tourneyid`
 AND r.`day1_best` = filter.`day1_best`
WHERE filter.`tourneyid` IS NOT NULL;
```

**[SQL DEMO](http://rextester.com/TLH91700)**

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Please try this :

```
   Select tp.tp_id , tp.resultid ,r.day1_best from (Select * from Tourneyplayers 
where tourneyid = 91)as tp inner join (select * from Result day1_best in(select 
day1_best from result group by day1_best having count(*)>1 ) )as r on tp.resultid  
= r.r_id ;
```

Comment: It still returns values which do not have duplicate day1_best.Added imgur link: http://imgur.com/a/LVNWm

Comment: (select 
day1_best from result group by day1_best having count(*)>1 ) this subquery returns the value they having duplicates.So there is no chance of getting displayed non duplicate values